# Animated TV show where this teen boy, girl, and man are a group and there are monsters; some are nice, some they fight

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

It was on Netflix, maybe early 2010s, because I remember watching it.

This boy was like a teen. The show was set in Paris, I think, so maybe it was French, because I remember Notre-Dame. The teen boy and the girl got together. Some of the monsters were like Pokémon and some of them they fought?

Comment: This question is quite terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the boy's name? What did he look like? Was he a young teen or nearly 20? What was the girl's name? What did the monsters look like? Did they need to summon them in some fashion? Was there a villain? Why did they fight their monsters? Did the baddies have monsters too? Who was the older man (a family member)? What was his name? What did he look like? Was it just one scene in Paris or the whole show set there?

Comment: [Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug & Cat Noir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous:_Tales_of_Ladybug_%26_Cat_Noir), features a boy and girl, and is set largely in Paris. Not a lot of other matching elements though;

Comment: The boy was older and so was the girl. There was a villain I just don't remember anything about that. They fought the villians monsters. They like looked for better monsters I think.

Comment: Since you accepted via a comment, I have marked your question as a duplicate. That does not mean that your question is bad, merely that it's one that we have had asked, and answered, before. You will still get points for upvotes. And you can still formally accept by clicking the checkmark by the answer (and get 2 points for doing so!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[Huntik: Secrets and Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)*** (2009–2012).

> *Huntik: Secrets & Seekers* is an Italian animated television series created by Iginio Straffi, the creator of *Winx Club*. It was produced by Rainbow, a studio co-owned by Straffi and Viacom at the time of the show's conclusion. **The series is about four adventurers who are part of a group called the Huntik Foundation. The Huntik team is led by their top operative Dante Vale. Every episode takes place in a different historical city and features magical elements inspired by European mythology.** The characters are designed in a style that combines Japanese anime with Western animation.

The show revolves around [Seekers](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Seekers); people who can summon monsters known as [Titans](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Titans) to fight at their sides, using magical [amulets](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Amulet) or [rings](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Ring).

> Seekers are people who can control Titans or utilize spells. Once a Seeker has bonded with a Titan's Amulet or Ring, that Titan can be summoned to fight at that Seeker’s side.

The 'good' Seekers belong to the [Huntik Foundation](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Huntik_Foundation), whereas the 'evil' ones (in the first season) belong to the [Organization](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/The_Organization), who mostly dress like Secret Service agents. Both sides are on the hunt for artefacts hidden in various cities.

The story begins in Venice, and the main characters in the first two episodes are a high school student named [Lok Lambert](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Lok_Lambert), his classmate, [Sophie Casterwill](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Sophie_Casterwill), an older detective, [Dante Vale](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Dante_Vale) -- one of the Huntik Foundation's top operatives, who trains Lok and Sophie to become Seekers -- and a small, flying Titan, [Cherit](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Cherit).

In episode 3, they visit Prague, where they're joined by [Zhalia Moon](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Zhalia_Moon), a young Seeker and spy who formerly worked for the Organization but is now allied with the Huntik Foundation.

In episode 5, they visit the [Cathedral of Notre Dame](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Cathedral_of_Notre_Dame) in Paris, which serves as one of the Huntik Foundation's bases.

> The Cathedral of Notre Dame, located in Paris, France, is a National monument amd major tourist attraction whilst also serving as a Huntik Foundation base.

Comment: This seems a far better match than Ladybug

Comment: It's this one lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be [*Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug & Cat Noir*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous:_Tales_of_Ladybug_%26_Cat_Noir)?

The show is set in Paris and features a teenaged boy and girl. They fight a range of costumed super-powered villains.

That being said, there isn't a lot of *Pokémon-style* battling here. The protagonists aren't possessed of monsters that they can summon and they don't use monsters to fight other trainer's monsters.